# How can I stop a here string (<<<) from adding a line break or new lines?

Tags: bash, herestring

It seems that `here string` is adding line break. Is there a convenient way of removing it?

```
$ string='test'
$ echo -n $string | md5sum
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  -
$ echo $string | md5sum
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
$ md5sum <<<"$string"
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
```

Comment: `<<<` also adds trailing newlines

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you are right: `<<<` adds a trailing new line.

You can see it with:

```
$ cat - <<< "hello" | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
```

Let's compare this with the other approaches:

```
$ echo "hello" | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
$ echo -n "hello" | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
$ printf "hello" | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
```

So we have the table:

```
         | adds new line |
-------------------------|
printf   |      No       |
echo -n  |      No       |
echo     |      Yes      |
<<<      |      Yes      |
```

From [Why does a bash here-string add a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20157/40596):

> Most commands expect text input. In the unix world, [a text file
>   consists of a sequence of lines, each ending in a
>   newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file/18789#18789).
>   So in most cases a final newline is required. An especially common
>   case is to grab the output of a command with a command susbtitution,
>   process it in some way, then pass it to another command. The command
>   substitution strips final newlines; `<<<` puts one back.

Comment: Also, note that a here-string is a shortcut for a single-line here document, which always ends with a newline.

Answer (score 7):

[fedorqui's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37728931/45375) shows **that and why here-strings (and also here-documents) *invariably append a newline***.

As for:

> Is there a convenient way of removing it?

In Bash, use `printf` inside a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) as an **"`\n`-less" alternative to a here-string**:

```
... < <(printf %s ...)
```

Applied to your example:

```
$ md5sum < <(printf %s 'test')
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

Alternatively, as [user202729](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5267751/user202729) suggests, simply **use `printf %s` in the pipeline**, which has the added advantage of not only using a more familiar feature but also making the command work in (more strictly) POSIX-compliant shells (in scripts targeting `/bin/sh`):

```
$ printf %s 'test' | md5sum
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

Answer (score 2):

As a "here doc" add a newline:

```
$ string="hello test"
$ cat <<_test_ | xxd
> $string
> _test_
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 7465 7374 0a              hello test.
```

Also a "here string" does:

```
$ cat <<<"$string" | xxd
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 7465 7374 0a              hello test.
```

Probably the easiest solution to get an string non-ending on newline would be `printf`:

```
$ printf '%s' "$string" | xxd
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 7465 7374                 hello test
```