# Difference between empty string and empty file

Tags: bash

I find it confusing that I can read once from an empty string, but not from an empty file:

```bash
while read -r foo; do echo ${#foo}; done <<< ''      # prints '0'
while read -r foo; do echo ${#foo}; done < /dev/null # prints nothing
```

Is there a way to write a string literal that cannot be read from even once? Conversely, what contents does a file need to have, in order to be able to read exactly one empty string from it, and nothing else?

Comment: Depends on what you are hoping to accomplish. A here string inherently has a newline at the end, but `printf %s "$foo"` does not.

Comment: See [How can I stop a here string (<<<) from adding a line break or new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37728699/4154375) and [Why does Bash always add a newline when expanding here strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33245568/4154375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [bash manual description of here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings):

> **3.6.7 Here Strings**
>
> A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<< word
> ```
>
> The word undergoes tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,
> command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.
> Filename expansion and word splitting are not performed. The result is
> supplied as a single string, **with a newline appended**, to the command
> on its standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified).

Note "with a newline appended". Even if your string starts out empty, it ends up containing at least a newline when used in this fashion. A string or file containing just a newline will be interpreted as one blank line by the `while read` loop.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to write a string literal that cannot be read from even once?

Yes, bash appends a line break to here-strings but an empty here-document is truly empty.

```
while read foo; do echo ${#foo}; done <<EOF
EOF
```

> Conversely, what contents does a file need to have, in order to be able to read exactly one empty string from it, and nothing else?

A single line break. You can create such a file with this command:

```
echo >file
```

Comment: Thank you for these precise answers. Still I have accepted Kensters answer, because it highlights the behaviour of the "here string", which I did not expect.