# bash - have read respect newlines (i.e. \n) contained on a string

Tags: bash

I have a function that returns several string separated by "|" and i am using read to parse them in tokens. Some of the strings might contain newlines (i.e. \n) but from my perspective read is removing them.

This is a simplified version of my code where i am able to reproduce the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

sMABz_IFS="|"

MABzBuildAlert ()
{
        read -r -d '' pThirdFieldTwoLines << sAPPEND_STRING_EOM_2
INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101
sAPPEND_STRING_EOM_2

        echo "FirstField${sMABz_IFS}SecondField${sMABz_IFS}${pThirdFieldTwoLines}${sMABz_IFS}FourthField"
}

 sMABzAlert=`MABzBuildAlert`

echo "** Using \`\` , echo and read -r**"
echo "sMABzAlert:[$sMABzAlert]"
IFS=\'"$sMABz_IFS"\' read -r sFirstField sSecondField sThirdFieldTwoLines sFourthField<<< `echo "${sMABzAlert}"`
echo "sFirstField:[$sFirstField]"
echo "sSecondField:[$sSecondField]"
echo "sThirdFieldTwoLines:[$sThirdFieldTwoLines]"
echo "sFourthField:[$sFourthField]"
echo
```

This is the output i am getting:

```
$ POC.sh
\*\* Using \`\` , echo and read -r\*\*
sMABzAlert:\[FirstField|SecondField|INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101|FourthField\]
sFirstField:\[FirstField\]
sSecondField:\[SecondField\]
sThirdFieldTwoLines:\[INTFARE.D240319.T1100 INTFARE.D240319.T1101\]
sFourthField:\[FourthField\]
```

What i am expecting is to have this output:

```
$ POC.sh
\*\* Using \`\` , echo and read -r\*\*
sMABzAlert:\[FirstField|SecondField|INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101|FourthField\]
sFirstField:\[FirstField\]
sSecondField:\[SecondField\]
sThirdFieldTwoLines:\[**INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101**\]
sFourthField:\[FourthField\]
```

Note:
I have tried with few other variants of read, including these:

```
IFS=\'"$sMABz_IFS"\' read sFirstField sSecondField sThirdFieldTwoLines sFourthField<<< `echo "${sMABzAlert}"`

IFS=\'"$sMABz_IFS"\' read -r sFirstField sSecondField sThirdFieldTwoLines sFourthField<<<"${sMABzAlert}"

IFS=\'"$sMABz_IFS"\' read -r sFirstField sSecondField sThirdFieldTwoLines sFourthField<<<"$(echo "${sMABzAlert}")"


IFS=\'"$sMABz_IFS"\' read -a sField <<<$(echo "${sMABzAlert}")
echo "sThirdFieldTwoLines:[${sField[2]}]"

IFS=\'"$sMABz_IFS"\' read -r -a sField <<<$(echo "${sMABzAlert}")
```

But neither gave me the result i am expecting.

Comment: What's the intent behind the herestring running the process substitution running `echo`? It seems really weird (and introduces several configuration-specific potential bugs) to use ```... <<<`echo $foo`;``` instead of `... <<<"$foo"`

Comment: Also, you almost certainly don't want to be adding literal single quotes to IFS. They absolutely do not do what you intend: IFS is a collection of literal characters, so `IFS=\'abc\'` is exactly 100% identical to `IFS=cba\'`. One quote character would make sense if you wanted that character to be part of the set; two just implies a misunderstanding of how IFS works.

Comment: Do you mean on the same line as read? No specific reason, i also tried one without echo but it didn't work either.

Comment: The quoted IFS is needed because i am using "|" as IFS, but we can probably have an off topic discussion for it.

Comment: What he's referring to are the escaped single quotes in ```IFS=\'...```

Comment: You can just write `IFS="$sMABz_IFS"`. The double quotes prevent processing the `|` inside the value of `sMABz_IFS`, and the single quotes are being added literally.

Comment: The thing is, _literal single quotes don't work as quotes at all_. You aren't quoting a value when you put `\'` before and after it -- instead, you're prepending and appending the `'` character to the _content_ of the value being assigned. It would need to just be `'` _without_ the backslash to work as a quote. (Because you have _double_ quotes inside, your value is quoted, but the single quotes are just prepending and appending literal values to that double-quoted string).

Comment: It's not going to have any effect unless there are single quote characters in the data you're parsing, so it's probably not related to the problem you're having.

Comment: (BTW, consider me to have cosigned everything Barmar says above).

Comment: For the sake of piece of mind i changed it to IFS="$sMABz_IFS" but it didn't solve the actual issue i described on this post, that read is removing the new lines (i.e. \n)

Comment: `read -r -d ''` _doesn't_ remove newlines. Doesn't happen. Full-stop. Anything that appears to lead you to think it does is based on an incorrect interpretation of the data at hand.

Comment: Mind, _one_ thing that might lead you to have that impression is that your second `read` doesn't have `-d ''` on it, so it's using the default `-d $'\n'` and only reading up to the first newline.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Another suggestion: stop using `echo` for debugging. It's a horribly buggy tool itself; `declare -p varname` is _much_ more reliable than `echo "varname:[$varname]"` -- the `declare -p` output is escaped so every character in it is printable, shows if you've got an array or other unusual datatype, etc.

Comment: (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo for an extensive writeup if you're curious about my statements about `echo`'s lack of reliability; or, for something shorter but less exhaustive, see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the POSIX standard for `echo` itself, at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)

Comment: (the other thing about `declare -p varname1 varname2` is that its output is code that, if copied-and-pasted, can be used to define the listed variables exactly as they were when that command was run, so it makes it easy to reproduce the state of your variables for debugging purposes)

Comment: I changed it to use read -r -d '', and it only added a newline at the end of $sFourthField but still removed the newlines from $sThirdFieldTwoLines

Comment: See [How can I stop a here string (<<<) from adding a line break or new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37728699/4154375) and [Why does Bash always add a newline when expanding here strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33245568/4154375) for explanations of the newline in `$sFourthField`.

Comment: The original problem may be due to a bug in earlier versions of bash (I think it was fixed in v4.3). If a here-string wasn't quoted, it'd be word-split and then reassembled from the words, with the effect of turning all whitespace (e.g. newlines) into spaces. Double-quoting the here-string properly (and preferably removing the pointless `echo`+backticks combo -- exactly as @CharlesDuffy suggested in the very first comment) should solve this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144593/trying-to-split-a-string-into-two-variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup:

```
sMABzAlert='FirstField|SecondField|INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101|FourthField'
```

Append a character on the end of our data, a character that does not show up in the data (eg, `%`):

```
$ echo "${sMABzAlert}"
FirstField|SecondField|INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101|FourthField

$ echo "${sMABzAlert}%"                          # add '%' on the end of string
FirstField|SecondField|INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101|FourthField%               # output terminated by a '%'
```

Tell `read` to read until the first `%` it comes to (`-d'%'`):

```
IFS='|' read -r -d'%' sFirstField sSecondField sThirdFieldTwoLines sFourthField <<< "${sMABzAlert}%"
```

The results:

```
$ typeset -p sFirstField sSecondField sThirdFieldTwoLines sFourthField
declare -- sFirstField="FirstField"
declare -- sSecondField="SecondField"
declare -- sThirdFieldTwoLines=$'INTFARE.D240319.T1100\nINTFARE.D240319.T1101'
declare -- sFourthField="FourthField"
```

Running OP's last 4 `echo` calls generates:

```
sFirstField:[FirstField]
sSecondField:[SecondField]
sThirdFieldTwoLines:[INTFARE.D240319.T1100
INTFARE.D240319.T1101]
sFourthField:[FourthField]
```

Comment: Based on all comments provided i attempted several options, but this one is the only one that completely solves my problem. It's worth to highlight that the use of -d option on read is the one that preserves the newlines on  sThirdFieldTwoLines, but the use of an extra delimiter character (i.e. '%') solves an additional issue where a newline is appended by read at the end of sFourthField.